# To calculate unaffected part of the data set with missing values and positive skewness

Tags: missing-data

A dataset has some missing values with positive skewness = 1. It is known that it is spread over 1.5 standard deviation from the median. How much % of data will remain unaffected?

Answer (score 0):

the data is spread across median, let’s assume it’s a normal distribution. We know, in a normal distribution, ~68% of the data lies in 1 standard deviation from mean (or mode, median), which leaves ~32% of the data unaffected. Therefore, ~32% of the data would remain unaffected by missing values.

Comment: what is the use of skewness here? and the standard deviation is 1.5